# Jquery MouseOver Events - Child is invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing a bit of code that mimics the F12 inspect tool that most browsers have. When hovering over an element, a div is appended with a semi-transparent blue colour, indicating that it's selected:

The problem that I'm having is that when moving the cursor over the child of an 'inspected' element, the child element does not actually get hovered:

Before Hover:

[image]

After Hover:

[image]

Here's my code ([JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/nutapigizi/edit?html,js,output)):

```js
$('body *').on('mouseover', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.inspect_hover').length == 0) {
    $('<div class=\'inspect_hover\'></div>').appendTo(e.target);
  }
}).on('mouseout', function(e) {
  var mouse = [e.pageX, e.pageY];
    var min = [$(e.target).offset().left, $(e.target).offset().top];
    var max = [($(e.target).offset().left + $(e.target).width()), ($(e.target).offset().top + $(e.target).height())];
    if (!(mouse[0] >= min[0] && mouse[0] <= max[0]) || !(mouse[1] >= min[1] && mouse[1] <= max[1])) {
      $('div.inspect_hover').remove();
    }
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.header h3 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.inspect_hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: rgba(126, 103, 238, 0.125) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='header'>
    <h3>Hello, World</h3>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How would I change my JS so that when hovering over the child, the child element is also 'inspected'?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want that html during inspect

Comment: <div class=\'inspect_hover\'></div> is html :P

Comment: Yes, the HTML that is in the append to line is the inspect colour element.

Comment: why don't just paste it <div class=\'inspect_hover\'></div> and remove js

Comment: Ok, let's say I've done that. I'd use JS 'addClass()' to make the inspect visible when mouseover is triggered. The problem still exists of the child-parent hover relationship. That's what this question is about.

Comment: may be i am not understanding $('div.inspect_hover').remove(); is removing html thats why it will not there

Comment: The only reason the HTML is added is so that the event can be visualised. The remove() is to rid of the coloured overlay that the 'inspecting' places on the element once it's no longer being hovered over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prependTo` instead of `appendTo`

```js
$('body *').on('mouseover', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.inspect_hover').length == 0) {
    $('<div class=\'inspect_hover\'></div>').prependTo(e.target);
  }
}).on('mouseout', function(e) {
  var mouse = [e.pageX, e.pageY];
    var min = [$(e.target).offset().left, $(e.target).offset().top];
    var max = [($(e.target).offset().left + $(e.target).width()), ($(e.target).offset().top + $(e.target).height())];
    if (!(mouse[0] >= min[0] && mouse[0] <= max[0]) || !(mouse[1] >= min[1] && mouse[1] <= max[1])) {
      $('div.inspect_hover').remove();
    }
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.header h3 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.inspect_hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: rgba(126, 103, 238, 0.125) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='header'>
    <h3>Hello, World</h3>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```